# on_notify fails to compile

Tags: smart-contract, event

I'm following the guidance at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/notification-handlers where it states I can decorate a method with:

```
[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer”)]]
```

however, when I do I get the following error:

> /var/folders/8q/q2rvsm3d2pj6fwbth49cp3r00000gn/T//dapp.cpp:270:16:
>   error: excess elements in struct initializer
>   dapp::TST{eosio::name{r},eosio::name{c},ds}.eos_receipt(arg0,
>   arg1, arg2, arg3);}}
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error:
>   cannot open
>   /var/folders/8q/q2rvsm3d2pj6fwbth49cp3r00000gn/T//dapp.cpp.o: No such
>   file or directory
>   *

can anyone suggest what the issue is? I'm currently running CDT 1.6.1

*** Edit I ***

an upgrade to CDT 1.6.3 did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah. I was naïvely placing the method on a class that's not a contract class. my bad